# Is there an option in Resharper C++ to convert functions/methods to trailing return types?

Tags: c++, resharper

Is there an option in Resharper to convert functions/methods to trailing return types?

From

```
int MyClass::add(int a, int b) const
```

to

```
auto MyClass::add(int a, int b) const -> int
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in ReSharper C++ at the moment. I filed a feature request (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSCPP-17722), please vote for it to receive updates.